# Hadoop command-line configuration not overriding defaults?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am having trouble accessing command-line configuration arguments for a Hadoop `Tool` implementation.

I am executing with the command: `hadoop jar <jar> <mainclass> -D SomeProperty=NewValue`

The `run(String[] args)` method begins:

```
Configuration configuration = this.getConf();
configuration.set("SomeProperty", "DefaultValue");
Options options = new Options();
GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(configuration, options, args);
args = parser.getRemainingArgs();

if (configuration.get("SomeProperty").equals("DefaultValue"))
    return 1; //Will always return here unless the default value is overridden
```

The property `SomeProperty` is never being set to `NewValue`.  New properties without default values are set in the configuration just fine, so it appears as though the problem is that command-line arguments aren't overriding the default configuration values.

Why is this happening? Can I change this behavior?

EDIT: To clarify, if I invoke the jar command with `hadoop jar <jar> <mainclass> -D SomeProperty=NewValue -D SecondProperty=OtherValue`, than `SecondProperty` will be set appropriately in the configuration and `SomeProperty` will not, and the only difference between the two is that when the `GenericOptionsParser` is used the configuration has already called `set("SomeProperty", "DefaultValue")`.

Comment: are you giving space between -D and property name? You shouldn't enter space between -D and param name. Post exact command name and values you have entered

Comment: Ravindra, either works just fine for setting properties at the command line in newer Hadoop versions.  The question is about the behavior of GenericOptionsParser and it failing to override properties previously defined via set().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my misunderstanding of the responsibilities of [`ToolRunner`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html#run(org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool,%20java.lang.String[])).

The documentation notes (emphasis mine):

> Runs the given Tool by Tool.run(String[]), *after parsing with the given generic arguments.* Uses the given Configuration, or builds one if null. Sets the Tool's configuration with the possibly modified version of the conf.

I was under the mistaken impression that using the generic options parser was the `Tool`'s responsibility.